# About Trivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I am working on a paper, and have a problem regarding ellipsoid and Trivariate Normal Distribution. Suprisingly I can't find much in literature but I found your in one of your answers:

> Because this construction has nothing to do with "confidence" per se,
>   the objective is to establish some convention for describing the shape
>   and relative size of the points. Using 1.96 sort of works (for three
>   variables): it contains about 72% of the probability of the trivariate
>   normal distribution. But as the number of variables increases this
>   method produces ellipses that are far too small. For instance, with 10
>   variables it will contain only 4.6% of the probability; using 4.28
>   instead of 1.96 in this case will contain 95% of the probability.

How did you get this number 72%? Or do you have some literature to recommend to me in which I can find this. I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: For starters go to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrivariateNormalDistribution.html   -it contains also literature references

Comment: Which answer are you quoting?

Comment: @Glen_b The comment at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67422/volume-of-the-95-confidence-ellipsoid/67429#comment130300_67429. The question starting that thread explains the chi-squared origin of these numbers and contains a couple of links.

Answer (score 6):

If $X \sim N_k(\mu,\Sigma)$, then $Q=(X-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu) \sim \chi^2_k$. Further, the [level sets of $Q$ are the ellipsoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Generalised_equations) you refer to. So the 72% you mention comes from a chi-square distribution (these calcs in R):

```
> pchisq(1.96^2,df=3)
[1] 0.7209157
```

As do the other numbers:

```
> pchisq(1.96^2,df=10)
[1] 0.04579014

> sqrt(qchisq(0.95,df=10))
[1] 4.278672
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Prediction_Interval

Comment: We got 95% confidence ellipsoid for 3 principal components by PCA on the first sample, and wanted to check it with next smaller sample and got the result that 72% of cases are found inside of ellipsoid.  Are we right that explanation lies in the fact that ellipsoid contains  72% of the probability of the trivariate normal distribution?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite follow your explanation there. Could you clarify either your explanation of what you did or rephrase your question more precisely into a form that doesn't require an explanation of what you did at all?

Comment: Ok. This is the problem. I have three variables (say X,Y and Z) and their measurements from sample (X=[x1,x2,...xn],Y=[y1,y2,...yn],Z=[z1,z2,...zn]). On the basis of those measurements I want to define 95% confidence ellipsoid (in X,Y,Z coordinate space), so that I can infer that 95% of whole population (from which I took my sample) will fit in that ellipsoid.

Comment: Oh, that's a *very* different problem to the one you posted about; here you're also dealing with the fact that the parameter estimates of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are not the same as the population quantities, but are themselves random variables. No hint of this problem is present in the original question. You might like to post a new question discussing the issue you have here.